# Local vs Global imports python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I am not seeing an answer to this out there, so apologies if this is a duplicate. Basically, I am trying to understand how to force my interpreter (2.7) to import a module from site packages if there is a conflict. For example imagine you are running python from a directory (top_level) that has the following structure:

```
top_level
----cool_mod
    ----init.py
    ----sweet_module.py
```

but you have already installed sweet module to site packages. When in this directory (but no others) if you run:

```
from cool_mod.sweet_module import *
```

you will import from the local module, not the global one. Can I change this somehow?

This situation might arise from the case:

```
top_level

setup.py
----cool_mod
    ----init.py
    ----sweet_module.py
```

You can run cool_mod.sweet_module before installing if you working directory is top_level. But after installing you can import cool_mod.sweet_module from anywhere. However, if you ever import from this directory, even after installation, you still import the local copy

Comment: Why would `cool_mod.sweet_module` ever reference to a global `sweet_module`? You namespaced it, of course it won't reference the global.

Comment: but if you get out of the current directory, it will import the correct global module

Comment: oh, I understand you question. If your setup script installs the whole package, then to import from global you still have to import cool_mod.sweet_module (as cool mod might have loads of amazing modules)

Comment: Don't mix packages with modules. Stick to one pattern; either `sweet_module` is *always* part of the `cool_mod` package (and you won't have naming conflicts) or it is *always* a top-level module. Don't even try to support both modes.

Comment: I am not sure, that I have conveyed myself well. Will edit question

Comment: I have edited to hopefully make things clearer

Comment: Yes, Python adds the current directory to the start of the PYTHONPATH, this is by design. Don't use that directory as a working directory or manipulate `sys.path`. But mostly just don't do that, because the point is that when you are in that directory you are there to use that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting the site package directory at the begining of sys.path, and then import.

Or, use `imp.load_source` to load a module from specified path.

Comment: I see that this will do what I want. However, I agree with martijn that this is probably a bad idea and have not taken this advice and just restructured my project